# Call master page "CS" method using JQuery (ajax doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I've been working several hours trying to make a function call a method in my masterpage.cs, I've found that using someting like this could work:

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

But it didn't work I think it's because it's a .master file and not an .aspx.

I've tried this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Administrador.master.cs/leerdatos",
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
}
});
```

As far as I know I just have to change in the url the page name and the method name, I've tried with and without "cs" at the end.

Master Page name: Administrador.master,
Method I want to call: leerdatos.

and also, using developing tools from google chrome threw this message:

*POST http://localhost:55519/Administrador.master.cs/leerdatos 404 (Not Found
)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't expect this to work since master pages are not directly accessible from the outside.

I would recommend to use a regular ASPX. You might have luck with the deriving ASPX which can call the method from the master page, or make a distinct ASPX page for these functions.